# If Array is collection of same data type then how to store different data types in one Array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

Actually the expert of java says, you can do this by using object of Object class which is cosmic superclass in java.If this is possible then how we can defines an Array is collection of same data type??

Comment: what do you mean? You can define an array of the same data type very easily: String[] strs = new String[10];

Comment: Your hire a carpenter, ask him to build a cage  to fit any birds. Now, you should be able to fit parrot or hawk or any thing that IS-A bird. summary: You can fit any type of java bird if the array cage is build for Object bird since all java bird are Object bird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, an array is **not** a `Collection`. Your *expert* seems to be refering to an array of the root type like,

```
 Object[] array = { "Test", 1, 1.0 };
 for (Object obj : array) {
   System.out.println(obj.getClass());
 }
```

Output is

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Double
```

This is possible because every Java type extends [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (implicitly or explicitly) and Java can [autobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) primitive types. From the Javadoc -

> Class `Object` is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has `Object` as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

Comment: From [Arrays: The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), *An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created.* Compare that to [`java.util.Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). Note that array does **not** implement `Collection`.

Comment: yes i agree with you,but what about the defination of array that says,"Array is collection of same data type".                         This defination comes in c++ and same follows in java.check the reference links http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/g/arraydefn.htm  http://www.techopedia.com/definition/1143/array-java

Comment: yes,java is not c++,but defination of array is not changed.

Comment: and I am asking the same is we define the array in java that "An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type".

Comment: Because a `Collection` has a *specific* meaning in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done (as shown in other answers), but usually it's not a very good practice to store objects of different types in one collection (not sure if you are referring to arrays or Collections such as ArrayList, but it doesn't matter), since it's not type safe, and forces you to use multiple `instanceof`s and castings in order to do anything meaningful with the elements of that array/collection.

If you are going to store objects of different unrelated types in your array/collection, you'd be better off creating a class that groups those objects in a meaningful way and using an array/collection containing only objects of your class.

```
public MyClass 
{
    String aString;
    int anInt;
    double aDouble;
    ...
    public MyClass (String a, int b, double c) 
    {
        this.aString = a;
        this.anInt = b;
        this.aDouble = c;
    }
    ...
}

MyClass [] array = { new MyClass("Test", 1, 1.0) , new MyClass("Test2", 2, 2.0) };
```

This way you can do stuff like :

```
for (MyClass obj : array)
    if (obj.getaString().contains("something")) {}
```

If you just throw all the objects into an Object array (Object[]), you can't do something like array[0].contains("something"), since `Object` doesn't have a `contains` method, and if you cast array[0] to String, you run the risk of ClassCastException if you don't check the type of array[0] first.

Comment: First I am saying thanks to all ,I agree that it is possible that array can store the values of different data types using super class Object.It is another thing that it is safe or not...now the quastion arise that the defination of array is right..??

Answer (score 0):

Because when you declare the array you specify a data type.  Every object in the array has this data type either directly or through a superclass.  Example:

```
Person[] people = new Person[3];
people[0] = new Employee();// where Employee extends Person
people[1] = new Teacher(); // where Teacher extends Person
people[2] = new Person();
```

All of these objects have Person as their superclass. This is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is true.

Let's say you have two classes: Animal and Plant and one object of these classes:

```
Animal cat = new Animal();
Plant tree = new Plant();
```

Store them in a Collection of Object Type:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();

myList.add(cat);
myList.add(tree);
```

Since the Animal and Plant class are descendents of Object class (in Java everything is descendent of Object class), and your Collection can hold objects of type Object, you can add this two objects into your collection.